# Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileInfo().Exists returns 400 bad request for encrypted files

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am using C# and AWSSDK v3 to upload files into an S3 bucket.  The file is encrypted using ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod.  I can upload the file, but if I check if the file exists using S3FileInfo().Exists, an error is thrown as a (400) Bad Request.  However, if I comment out the lines that specify encryption in the upload routine, the S3FileInfo().Exists finds the file without throwing an error.  What I am doing wrong? Or is there a different way to check if a file exists when it is encrypted?

Here is my upload routine:

```
       public static string wfUpload(Stream pFileStream, string pBucketName, string pKeyName, string pCryptoKey) {
        string retVal = "";
        try {
            using (var lS3Client = new AmazonS3Client()) {
                Aes aesEncryption = Aes.Create();
                aesEncryption.KeySize = 256;
                aesEncryption.GenerateKey();
                string lCryptoKey = Convert.ToBase64String(aesEncryption.Key);

                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest {
                    BucketName = pBucketName,
                    Key = pKeyName,
                    ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod = ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod.AES256,
                    ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey = lCryptoKey,
                };

                request.InputStream = pFileStream;
                PutObjectResponse response = lS3Client.PutObject(request);

                retVal = lCryptoKey;
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception) {
            Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message,
                              s3Exception.InnerException);

            throw (s3Exception);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

And my routine to check if the file exists or not:

```
       public static bool wfFileExists(String pBucketName, String pKeyName) {
        bool retVal = false;
        try {
            using (var lS3Client = new AmazonS3Client()) {
                if (new Amazon.S3.IO.S3FileInfo(lS3Client, pBucketName, pKeyName).Exists) {
                    retVal = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception) {
            Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message,
                              s3Exception.InnerException);

            throw (s3Exception);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the class/method I was using is one of the high level APIs that doesn't support encryption.  I changed my code to do a meta-data query to see if anything comes back.  If it can't find the file it throws a "NotFound" ErrorCode in the s3Exception that I check for. Hopefully this helps someone else.  If someone else suggests a better approach, I'd love to learn it too.

```
        public static bool wfFileExists(String pBucketName, String pKeyName, String pCryptoKey) {
        bool retVal = false;
        try {
            using (var lS3Client = new AmazonS3Client()) {
                GetObjectMetadataRequest request = new GetObjectMetadataRequest {
                    BucketName = pBucketName,
                    Key = pKeyName,
                    ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod = ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod.AES256,
                    ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey = pCryptoKey,
                };

                GetObjectMetadataResponse lMetaData = lS3Client.GetObjectMetadata(request);

                // If an error is not thrown, we found the metadata.
                retVal = true;
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception) {
            Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message,
                              s3Exception.InnerException);

            if (s3Exception.ErrorCode != "NotFound") {
                throw (s3Exception);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```